# How qsort() function works?

Tags: c, qsort

```
void qsort (
    void* base,
    size_t num,
    size_t size,
    int (*compar)(const void*,const void*)
);
```

How qsort function access "size" byte after adress to get next element?
By typecasting `void*` to `char*`?

Comment: `qsort` implementations are mostly open-source.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Given that, I am voting to close as a request for offsite resources

Comment: Here is the first result from Googling "glibc qsort": https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/qsort.c

Comment: The answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

> How does the qsort function access "size" bytes after the base address to get the next element? By typecasting `void*` to `char*`?

The assumption inherent in the question is that `qsort` is itself written in C; it need not be. Let's assume that it is.

A conversion to `char*` would be a typical way of doing it, yes, either by explicitly using a cast operator, or by assigning `base` to a local variable of type `char*`.

GNU C allows you to add an integer to a void pointer directly, but that is a non-portable extension to the C language.

If you have a question about a *specific* implementation, say what implementation.